# triangulation of pair of pants

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces

How can we triangulate a pair of pants in a simple way?  I am looking for some triangulation where I can compute the Euler characterstic easily (which is -1 for a pair of pants).

Comment: Draw one and start subdividing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one:

[image]

20 vertices, 43 edges and 22 triangles.

Comment: Notice that there are other, simpler ways of computing the characteristic of this space: for example, it deformation-retracts on the join of two circles (that is, a figure $\infty$), so we can triangulate the latter space, which is of course easy.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This is because pair of pants is homeomorphic to a disk with two holes.